# POST method working even the if condition fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I hava  a form element with some contents inside as given below.

```
<form action="insertserverdata.php" id="toPopup">
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>IP address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ip" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Port:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="port" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the following jQuery code.

```
$("#toPopup").submit(function(event){
    if($('#ip').val()=="") {
        alert("IP field is Empty");
    }else if($('#port').val()=="") {
        alert("Port field is Empty");
    }else {
      //else code to be executed.
    }
});
```

Here the last else block of this else-if ladder contains the code for posting data to insertserverdata.php. And my intention is to redirect to insertserverdata.php only if the two text fields are populated with some data. But when I click submit button the with no text inside text fields, the if blocks of jquery will works fine and after that it will redirect to insertserverdata.php page, but i dont want that.What change shall I need to full fill that?. Please help me friends.

Comment: ip and port have the same id!

Comment: Sorry dear. That was my mistake. Actaully I was copying the same. I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to return **false** on each invalid check like

```
$("#toPopup").submit(function(event){
    if($('#ip').val()=="") {
       alert("IP field is Empty");
       return false;
    }else if($('#port').val()=="") {
       alert("Port field is Empty");
       return false;
    }
    //Do the stuff 
});
```

And one more thing ,change the id's of two text boxes to 'ip' and 'port' at your html

Comment: This works fine dude :) Thanks :) will given green tick mark as i cannot do it until 15 minutes !.

Comment: @Gautam3164 also you can trim both ip and port values...otherwise sometimes you will get problem.

Comment: Thats tru sachin. sometimes trimming data required.

Comment: I will also obey with you sachin,we need to do it

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$("#toPopup").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#ip').val()=="") {
        alert("IP field is Empty");
    }else if($('#port').val()=="") {
        alert("Port field is Empty");
    }else {
       //else code to be executed.
       return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which should show both error messages then returns true instead of showing one or the other error message if both are empty.

```
$("#toPopup").submit(function(event){
    var errors = false;
    if($.trim($('#ip').val())=="") {
        alert("IP field is Empty");
        errors = true;
    }
    if($.trim($('#port').val())=="") {
        alert("Port field is Empty");
        errors = true;
    }
    if(errors){
        return false;
    }else{
        //else code to be executed.
    }
});
```